# How do you do a LOCATE in Unidata with BASICTYPE 'U' for @AM's?

Tags: u2, unidata

I typically use BASICTYPE 'P' at our shop but had an occasion to use 'U' for a project and noticed that I could not do a locate on a dynamic array that is delimited by Attribute Marks.

Referencing the docs, it plainly states that in type U, not specifying an attribute expression is a syntax error.  This seems like a huge oversight to me.

How would this be done without resorting to a for-loop to search for these items?

Comment: I think the question is a little misleading.  The title gives the impression that you're seeking to locate attribute marks.  The detail of the question is pretty clear that you're seeking to locate within an attribute marked dynamic array.

Answer (score 2):

If your array is delimited by attribute marks, you simply need to do your locate in the following syntax:

```
LOCATE expression IN array_name SETTING position_var THEN | ELSE ...
```

It's a bit trickier to locate within a value mark delimited array, which would be:

```
LOCATE expression IN array_name<1> SETTING position_var THEN | ELSE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms of the LOCATE statement

One takes the form of Locate xxx in yyy setting zzz then aaa else bbb
and the other
Locate(xxx;yyy;zzz) then aaa else bbb

Comment: This doesnt appear to answer my question.  Does the funtion version of LOCATE() not have this BASICTYPE difference?

Answer (score 0):

When in BASICTYPE 'U', you could use the FIND statement instead.

From the manual:

**Syntax**
`FIND expr IN dyn.array[,occur] SETTING f [,v[,s]] {THEN statements | ELSE statements}`

**Description**
The UniBasic FIND command determines the position of the given expression in a 
dynamic array. FIND returns the attribute, value, and subvalue position of the found 
string. The expression must match the entire array element to make a matc